# IOS core plot hide 0-100 part of x axis makes y axis disapear

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

Hiding 0-100 part of x axis, by setting visible range to 0-100, makes y axis disapear

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely not disappeared, rather it could be on the left/right of the screen, assuming that both the axes don't intersect at (0,0). If you enable interaction on plot space (plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;) you might be able to pinch zoom and take a look around if its there or not.

Also, you can try to make the axes 'fixed' by adding constraints to them:

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;

// Configure x-axis
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;

x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:50];
y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:50];
```